# Why do almost all of the C++ standard libraries not portable (including those of clang, gcc, and vc++)?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, standards-compliance, std

I failed to compile gcc's C++ standard library with VC++, and vice versa.

Why do almost all of the C++ standard libraries not portable (including those of clang, gcc, and vc++)?

I also tried STLport, however, it is too old to support C++11.

I'm writing my own mini-STL for embedded systems, where I cannot use the compiler-provided STL because of its non-portability. So, I must care this.

Is there an implementation of the portable C++ standard library?

Comment: Which parts failed to compile? Did you check that? C++11 threads for example need to be implemented OS specific. File I/O is also OS specific.

Comment: `type_info` is tightly linked to the compiler, even for two compilers running on the same system.  As is `numeric_limits`, and probably most of section 18.

Comment: There have been some cross-compiler implementations of at least part of the Standard libraries in the past, such as SGI STL (think it was abandoned in 2000), and STLport (2008).  They're too old to be useful.  There're just too many hassles mixing your code with existing libraries created with the compiler's own library to make it worthwhile (e.g. how can you pass a `std::string` to a library if the memory layout or required behaviours to maintain invariants differ?).

Comment: "cannot use the compiler-provided STL because of its non-portability" - what're the actual issues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Part of the standard library's job is to provide portable wrappers around platform-dependent and compiler-dependent functionality. It *cannot* be fully portable.

There's also no reason why it *should* be portable. There's no need for it. It is supplied as part of the compiler toolchain. When you have a compiler, you also have a standard library implementation that works with that compiler. No matter which compiler you're using, you already *have* an implementation of the standard library.